# Adobe ANE platform options are ignored in iOS extension

Tags: ios, flash, ane

I have "successfully" created an almost empty ANE extension for iOS (no build errors) which uses Twitter framework.

But when I compile hello world example with my ANE,

```
amxmlc -library-path+=Plugin HelloWorld.as
adt -package -target ipa-debug -keystore iosPrivateKey.p12 -storetype pkcs12 -storepass qwerty12 -provisioning-profile ios.mobileprovision HelloWorld.ipa  HelloWorld-app.xml HelloWorld.swf -extdir Plugin
```

I got link error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWTweetComposeViewController", referenced from:
```

This suggests Twitter framework is not linked, but it should be because

My platformoptions.xml file:

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/13.0">
    <sdkVersion>5.1</sdkVersion>
    <linkerOptions>
        <option>-ios_version_min 4.0</option>
        <option>-framework Twitter</option>
    </linkerOptions>
</platform>
```

When I tried to modify this file and added some syntax mistakes, this lead to ANE build failure. So this file is used in the extension build. But its content is ignored in the build:

```
$ADT -package -target ane $NAME.ane extension.xml -swc $NAME.swc -platform iPhone-ARM library.swf lib$NAME.a -platformoptions platformoptions.xml
```